# Peek operation for semaphore

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, semaphore

Suppose we have defined  `Up()`, `Down()` and `Peek()` operations for semaphore and the `Peek()` operation returns the semaphore's value.

What are pros and cons of `Peek()` operation?

How can I effectively use `Peek()` operation?

Comment: It's for debugging and testing, mostly. You can't do much useful synchronization with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `peek` function is useless for synchronisation.  It only allows to see the current state, but no actions should be taken, because immediately after the peek, the semaphore can already be changed.  It could be used for monitoring to solve deadlocks, but this is very tricky.  As mentioned in the comments, it can help with debugging.

A `try` function is more useful.  That would only `down` the semaphore if possible and return a failed condition if not possible.  This way actions can be done if the semaphore is free and don't block if it is not (polling based).  Most of the times, using a different thread with just `up` and `down` gives better results (at least cleaner code)

Answer (score 1):

> [Assumung that the question is about OS's native semaphores.]

In WinAPI and Linux, semaphores are kernel objects, so it is possible to access the semaphore from an another process or even from an another application. Pure semaphores [are not just mutexes with an attached counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29#Semaphores_vs._mutexes). You can't just **up** and **down** the semaphore, there's no `Capture()` function to manually decrement the counter. But instead of doing this, you have `Wait()` and `Release()` functions. When the wait function returns, it decreases the semaphore's count by one. When the thread or the process has finished using the resource, it calls `Release()` to increase the semaphore's count by one.

What about `Peek()` yes, it's useless for the sync purposes. But you can check the semaphore for availability while debugging. Please try to avoid using `Peek()` for the sync purposes, try to deal with just `Wait()` and `Release()`.